# Batch actions with Sonata Admin Bundle on Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, frameworks, yaml, sonata

I need to get data grid on the controller but it does not allow to enter parameters in the function. How you recover that information?

```
services:
        admin.category:
                class: AppBundle\Admin\CategoryAdmin
                arguments: [~, AppBundle\Entity\Category, AppBundle:CRUDCategory, ~]            
                tags:
                    - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "General", label: Categories }
```

This is the controller

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController as SonataController;
use Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\Datagrid\ProxyQuery as ProxyQueryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class CRUDCategoryController extends SonataController {

    /**
     * @param ProxyQueryInterface $selectedModelQuery
     * @param Request             $request
     *
     * @return RedirectResponse
     */
    public function batchActionInactive(ProxyQueryInterface $selectedModelQuery, Request $request) {        
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $category = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')->find($request->getId());
        $category->setState('INACTIVE');
        $em->flush();
        return new RedirectResponse(
            $this->admin->generateUrl('list', $this->admin->getFilterParameters())
        );
    }

}
```

And this is the function getBatchActions

```
   public function getBatchActions() {
        $actions = parent::getBatchActions();
        unset($actions['delete']);
        $actions['inactive'] = array(
          'label' => 'Disable category',
          'ask_confirmation' => false
        );
        return $actions;
    }
```

The error is

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to
>   AppBundle\Controller\CRUDCategoryController::batchActionInactive()
>   must be an instance of AppBundle\Controller\Request, none given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is much easier, do it this way instead of getting the categories by your own:

```
/**
 * @param ProxyQueryInterface $selectedModelQuery
 *
 * @return RedirectResponse
 */
public function batchActionInactive(ProxyQueryInterface $selectedModelQuery)
{
    $selectedCategories = $selectedModelQuery->execute();

    try {
        /** @var Category $category */
        foreach ($selectedCategories as $category) {
            $category->setState('INACTIVE');
            $this->admin->update($category);
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->addFlash(
            'sonata_flash_error',
            'Could not mark Categories "INACTIVE"'
        );

        $this->get('logger')->error($e->getMessage());

        return new RedirectResponse($this->admin->generateUrl('list', $this->admin->getFilterParameters()));
    }

    $this->addFlash(
        'sonata_flash_success',
        'Categories were marked as "INACTIVE"'
    );

    return new RedirectResponse($this->admin->generateUrl('list', $this->admin->getFilterParameters()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Sonata and everything to do with Symfony : you forgot the use statement for `Request`. The `AppBundle\Controller\Request` should have made you realize that ;)

EDIT: second error : action methods should end with **Action*

Comment: Thanks , I've added the line `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;`, but the problem continues

Comment: see my edit, you did not put "action" in the right place

Comment: I followed this documentation [link](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/batch_actions.html#) though symfony handled as you mention , Sonata does with `batchActionInactive`

Comment: Indeed. So this is not supposed to be a standard Symfony action, which means you can't expect `$request` to be provided. Get it with `$this->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest()`

Answer (score 0):

I've already solved.

```
public function batchActionInactive(ProxyQueryInterface $selectedModelQuery) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $ids = $request->request->get('idx');
    foreach ($ids as $id) {
        $category = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')->find($id);
        $category->setState('INACTIVE');
        $em->flush();
    }
    return new RedirectResponse(
        $this->admin->generateUrl('list', $this->admin->getFilterParameters())
    );
}
```